JHipster 8.7.0 Upgrade with Angular gets Error: [eslint] Couldn't find FlatESLint
I upgraded from JHipster 8.6.0 to 8.7.0 and now my Angular gets several errors saying:
Error: [eslint] Couldn't find FlatESLint, you might need to set eslintPath to 'eslint/use-at-your-own-risk'
I noticed in the release notes there are mentions of migrating vue and React eslint to flat config, but nothing about migrating Angular ealint to flat config.
Is there a way to get around the error or is 8.7.0 not ready to be used with Angular?
I tried installing eslint web pack plugn and eslint using the following commands:
npm install eslint-webpack-plugin --save-dev npm install eslint --save-dev
But I still get the same error.
